# How to add a flashdata after session_write_close()

Tags: codeigniter, session, concurrency, codeigniter-3

I upgraded my application from CI2 to CI3 (CI v3.1.9 and PHP7). Now I have performance issue with the new concurrency system in the session (see [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#a-note-about-concurrency)).

Some of the actions in the application are very long (because of calling an external APIs that can takes several minutes to respond for example) and I don't want those actions to lock the session. As recommended, I would use `session_write_close()` function in the controller before doing the very long action.

The problem is that I want to display a message to user after redirecting at the end of this action. Right now, I am using `session->set_flashdata()` before the redirection, but because I closed the session earlier, it is not working.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to achieve that?

If I am starting the session again with `session_start()` it is working, but I have no idea if this is best practice to use PHP session like that with Codeigniter.

Comment: external api taking several MINUTES? that doesn't sound normal

Comment: I agree. But that's not our code...

Comment: honestly, i would suggest looking for other api's or finding a cron-like way of caching the data in a database if it is due to large datasets. irregardless, ci basically uses normal php sessions so starting the session again after closing it I wouldn't consider bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with starting the session again using `session_start()`. The CodeIgniter "Session" class is still loaded and the instance is still valid. So all the "special" stuff that CI does to make sessions work is good to go.

I tested and then used this scheme in a project some time back and didn't experience any problems. Haven't had any blow-back from the client of a still operating site either. YMMV.

BTW, in the `__construct()` function of the `CI_Session` class a call to `session_start()` is made in order to start up PHP's session extension. So making that call is clearly not a "bad" practice. :)